# Importing Google Maps/Fusion Tables into PowerBI via ShapeFiles

Tags: google-maps, powerbi, google-fusion-tables, topojson, powerbi-desktop

I'm having trouble importing maps from Google Maps + Fusion Tables into Power BI. This example is a map of 125 routes in the UK from 125 different destinations to the same 1 final destination. I've attached some photos in the various stages of processing it, and what I want. Also the original files can be found here if people want to attempt this themselves: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15gOY3JV_rn9QB2K_bpOAMsNcQJwukYD4

Basically when I import into PowerBI, it looks like a mess and there is no real meaning to it.

What I've done:

1. Create these maps in Fusion Tables, then export as Shapefile.
2. Import Shapefile into MapShaper and overlay map of the UK.
   I use `-proj wgs84` command as I saw this in another forum.
3. Export both my map and the UK map together as a `topoJSON`.
4. Import a custom Shape map into  PowerBI.
   One thing I'm not sure how to do here is configure the "Location" Field of this Shape Map. Currently I arbitrarily dragged the "Name" column of my JSON, but I don't understand what this means.

Any help would be very much appreciated!! If there's a faster way to incorporate **.kml** files into PowerBI, then I would love to hear that too.

Attached images of my steps and what I want:

Fusion Tables - what I want

[image]

MapShaper - almost what I want

[image]

PowerBI - definitely not what I want...

[image]